# Visual studio 11 beta and .NET 4.5

Tags: visual-studio-2012

i have installed the new beta version 11 of visual studio and can't find how to change the app target to 4.5? i see then .NET 4.5 is successfully installed on my machine but in visual studio it is not listed as a target for application. Does anyone have any idea why?

Comment: Are you able to create a new project that targets .NET Framework 4.5?  (File -> New Project, the framework selection is in a combo box at the top of the dialog).

Answer (score 0):

I have a Windows 7 x64 and had the same problem, I couldn't choose ".NET Framework 4.5". After installing Windows 8 SDK, I was able to pick 4.5, but there where no templates. Running devenv.exe /installvstemplates made no difference and reinstalling Visual Studio did not help either.

I was trying to install http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/en-us/downloads#testpro (both via webinstaller and the iso) but it was first when I installed the non-test version of professional (got it from MSDN) that my project templates installed.

Hope this helps.